Maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 17164
I have a war project in java 1.8, It's mandatory to use maven-plugin-plugin version 3.2.  When I tried to install I had this error.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project FACFAC_WL: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 17164 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project FACFAC_WL: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 17164

I'm trying to install my project , I've implemented all the solutions I found
incluidng  source and target version, to specify  maven-plugin-plugin .... I always obtein the same error.
]

Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what is the issue or how to reproduce. See
[ask] for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. Then [edit] your question to add a [mre].

Thanks for your answer, but I can't  include a shortest code to reproduce it.  The best question, in my case it's if there are any place to finde  the error number code for the maven-plugin-plugin descriptor.

Why it is mandatory to use a version from 2014? The latest version released is still compatible with Java 8 if that is the concern: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Because it's the version the customer has, and in my case I don't have power to change it.
